# Keeping javascript alive on inactive brave tabs

Tags: browser, brave

I have some scripts that I'd like to run h24 using Tamper Monkey. The scripts are working fine but I'm using it on a separate tab and the tab just go inactive quite quickly. How can I prevent that from happening? Is there a way to keep inactive tabs "alive"?

It's quite a big issue for me as I'd need to have like almost 100 tabs open at once so they'll go dormant even faster I assume...

If there is no solution, is there a browser which would allow me to do that?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab suspension is a normal feature of just about all browsers today. Often JavaScript isn't halted entirely, but rather throttled until the tab is refocused. If you need more, you could consider using a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).